# Process expression string in Java [toLower,toUpper and concat]

Tags: java, regex, string, combinations, permutation

I have a regular expression with any combination of `toLower`, `toUpper`, and `concat` functions, eg. 
`inputString = concat(toLower(concat("ABC","xyz")),toUpper("pqr"))`
or `outputString = abcxyzPQR`.

Expression input string can have many combination of three functions [`toLower`,`toUpper` and `concat`].

How can I process the string with any random combination of above 3 functions in Java?

Comment: Can you add your code and point out where is your problem ?

Comment: If any combination and nesting level is possible then instead of regex you probably want to create proper *grammar* for all possible variants and parser for that grammar. I heard that https://github.com/antlr/antlr4 is nice tool for that kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class RandomCombination
    {

    public static void main(String args [])
    {
    Random randomGenerator=new Random(); // We will randomize between 1 to 3. We are adding in the random coz next(3) will randomize from 0-2
     String outputString= randomize("ABC",randomGenerator.nextInt(3)+1).concat(randomize("xyz",randomGenerator.nextInt(3)+1)).concat(randomize("pqr",randomGenerator.nextInt(3)+1));

     System.out.println(outputString);
    }
    static String randomize(String inputString, int ran )
    {
    String outuput;
    switch(ran){
        case 1:
        outuput=inputString.toUpperCase(); // if 1 use upper
        break;
        case 2:
        outuput= inputString.toLowerCase();  // if 2 use lower
        break;  
        default:
        outuput=inputString;  // if 3 don't do a thing
        }

        return outuput;
    }
    }

Sample output:
abcXYZPQR
abcxyzpqr
ABCXYZpqr
abcxyzPQR
abcXYZPQR
```

Comment: No. I don't want random output. Suppose my input string is "concat(toLower(concat("ABC","xyz")),toUpper("pqr"))" then outputString should be abcxyzPQR....So there can be any combination of toLower,toUpper and concat at any level.